# Plone - How can I check if User is on /folder_contents view action

Tags: plone, plone-4.x

Because I use plone.app.widgets (1.8.0) and wildcard.foldercontents (1.3.2), I have to disable pa.widgets-Javascript only for /folder_contents tab.

Multiupload does not work with pa.widgets enabled

```
 ().fileUpload is not a function
```

But how can I determine that?
What I've tried:

```
context/absolute_url  
context/@@plone_context_state/object_url
getViewTemplateId
and a few more
```

Plone 4.3.4.1

Comment: What `getViewTemplateId` is returning?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with *wildcard.foldercontents* and *collective.z3cform.widgets*..both have a related js code that goes in conflict.

i check that condition like this:

```
self.request.steps[-1] != "folder_contents"
```

In folder_contents tab, last step in the request is always "folder_contents".

I don't know if it's the best solution, but it works

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, just so simple

```
request.ACTUAL_URL
```

open for a better solution :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following code:

```
mt = getToolByName(self.context, 'portal_membership')
member = mt.getMemberById(username)
if member == 'Anonymous':
    pass
else:
    pass
```

And you can handle when is Anonymou or logged member.

Comment: Please add what your code does that helps solve the OP's problem (or explain when it's useful for yourself).

Answer (score 0):

In Plone 6:
using the View class

```
from Acquisition import aq_inner
from plone.app.content.browser.contents import FolderContentsView

# Get the current context
context = aq_inner(context)

# Check if the context is a FolderContentsView
if isinstance(context, FolderContentsView):
    print("You are inside a FolderContentsView")
else:
    print("You are not inside a FolderContentsView")
```

or with the interface:

```
from Acquisition import aq_inner
from plone.app.content.browser.interfaces import IFolderContentsView

# Get the current context
context = aq_inner(context)

# Check if the context provides the IFolderContentsView interface
if IFolderContentsView.providedBy(context):
    print("You are inside a FolderContentsView")
else:
    print("You are not inside a FolderContentsView")
```